# AppEngine: Memcache without any instance

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

My problem is my memcache resets every night. What could the be problem?

I have a very simple low-traffic web site on Google App Engine in Java. I do not have any instances left at night because of lack of traffic. If there is no instance, does it mean that memcache clears all its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memcache is not persistent and can be evicted by memory pressure. Share memcache is shared with other apps. You can buy dedicated memcache for reserved amount. What you described does not seem to be a problem at all.
One important question is, what is the timeout that you set?

Comment: I understand that memcache can be erased anytime. But i think it is not normal that it resets everynight. No problem during the day. I suspect it is releated with my instances. If there is no instance it means the memcache clears all the data in itself?

Comment: No memcache can be cleared at any time.  And is generally evicted if there is no activity.  It is just a cache and should not be relied on. Historically and anecdotally the oldest memcache entries are typically between 3 and 9 hours old for me.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I know "It is just a cache and should not be relied on. " concept very well. My question is: does my memcache cleared by the app engine when appengine ends my last instance beacause of lack of traffic?

Comment: @lembas not it doesn't.  With dedicated memcache the oldest item age for me is 15 days.